# False Positive Returned in wild card character search in Marklogic 7

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

I am executing an XQuery search against a word query to return values using co-occurrences. But the problem is that while executing a wild card search, then there are certain false positives that are returned as part of the matching documents.
The element word query executed is

```
cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("", "contents"), "project monitor*", 
  ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","stemmed","lang=en"), 1)
```

The query which is executed is

```
cts:element-value-co-occurrences(xs:QName("node1"), xs:QName("node2"),                            
  ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/"),
  cts:and-query((
        cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("", "node3"), "project monitor*", ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","stemmed","lang=en"), 1),
        cts:element-range-query(
            xs:QName("node4"),
            "=",
            xs:long('1234567891011')
        ),
        cts:element-attribute-range-query(
            xs:QName("node5"),  
            xs:QName("attribute1"),  
            "=",
            ""
        ),
        cts:collection-query('collection1'),
        ()    
    ))
)
```

It is returning two matching results, which has one positive and one has a false positive items.

```
<cts:co-occurrence>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">General</cts:value>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">/pdf/text-document/12345_0_1234.xml</ct‌​s:value>
</cts:co-occurrence> 
<cts:co-occurrence>
   <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">Other</cts:value>
   <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">/pdf/text-doc/1234_1_0000.xml</cts:value>
</cts:co-occurrence>
```

Comment: Can you post the two matches? It's likely related to your index settings.

Comment: <cts:co-occurrence xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">General</cts:value>
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">/pdf/text-document/12345_0_1234.xml</cts:value>
</cts:co-occurrence>
<cts:co-occurrence xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">Other</cts:value>
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string">/pdf/text-doc/1234_1_0000.xml</cts:valu

Comment: How are your documents structured? Are both of these values coming from the same document or different documents? What are the values that are matching the `cts:element-word-query` (the correct and the false positive one)?

Comment: These are coming from different documents. There are no matches that are highlighted as matching snippets and that is particularly the issue.

Comment: I think more important than the result of the co-occurrence would be to provide the actual document that gives the false positive against the search provided.

Answer (score 3):

Without a complete reproducible test case, my best guess is that a missing positional index is causing the wildcarded `cts:element-word-query` to return the false positive. Try enabling either or both: `element word positions` and `element value positions` in your database configuration and retry the query (after reindexing).

Comment: Also note that the query run by [cts:element-value-co-occurrences()](https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_89797) is evaluated as an unfiltered query. Showing a sample false-positive document would be helpful here.